# Unable to access my remote tomcat application using ip address

Tags: tomcat, remote-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I uploaded my web application in my remote tomcat server. In Remote desktop when i enter `localhost:8080/application` it is working fine. I am trying to open my application using ip address it is not opening `147.40.37.78:8080/application`.

How to access my tomcat application by using remote ip address?

Comment: any firewall? 
`netstat -na | find "8080"`
is tomcat listening on 147.40.37.48:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: I am using windows 2012 r2 server. Can you tell me where to find firewall..